# Is it unreasonable to ask too many questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, behavior

I find myself **asking a lot** of questions (like 500 or so over the past 5 years). Honestly, I feel like I abuse it. My backgroud though is that I code but I manage off-site developers in technologies that I'm not so familiar with.

Also, I often have to analyze something to see how well it would work in an environment (like today I've asked about 5 questions on Ember.js which I'm evaluating). I usually Google for an answer but often it's really difficult to find something that matches exactly what you're looking, especially when you don't have a deep understanding of the technology to start with. I guess my question is "**Is this behavior ok?**" Or is this really frowned upon?

Comment: Meh, anyone conscientious enough to ask this question is very likely to be asking good questions, so all is probably well.

Comment: thx Pëkka, maybe I just feel guilty and I ask a LOT

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "Is this behavior ok?" Or is this really frowned upon?

I've not seen a reference mentioning that this behavior is frowned upon. If you have, please share the reference with us. Rather, asking bad, inappropriate, poorly formed or incomplete questions, this is what is frowned upon. I also see that you have answered a fair number of questions and have received up-votes for both your answers and your questions. I'd suggest that you carry on, soldier.

Comment: cool, thx for answer. Yeah, that's a bit the way I feel. I know most stuff has been asked already but I like the idea of trying to ask and, as long as it's well written and people will / want to answer, I feel like it's ok. thx again

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: @0x7fffffff: that answer was a thing of beauty. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

> "Is this behavior ok?" Or is this really frowned upon?

If you are asking good, high quality question, then I don't see a problem. You are contributing to the community.

Without questions, there would be no Stack Overflow.

Aside from that, I believe there are limits on the number of questions you can ask within a certain period of time. You don't seem to be reaching that limit, as you are only asking ~2 questions a week.

I'd say you're fine.

Comment: thx Josh, I feel that way that it's a Q & A site.